# Doesn't get all products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get all products in WooCommerce and make a slider with theme.

So my code in `function.php` is:

```
function zf_theme_home_slide() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',        /* post type */
        'post_status' => 'publish',   /* post montasher shode */
        'orderby' => 'date',          /* moratab sazi bar asas tarikh — date , ID , author , type , name , title , parent , rand , comment_count — */
        'order' => 'DESC'             /* moratabsazi Soudi ya nozooli — DESK = Nozooli , ASC = Soudi */
    );
    $post_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ob_start();
    var_dump( $post_query);
    if($post_query->have_posts()) :
        ?>
        <div class="flexslider" >
            <ul class="slides">
                <?php    while ($post_query->have_posts()) :
                    $post_query->the_post();
                    //  if( get_field('slide_hn_theme') ){ 
                        $hn_permalink = get_the_permalink();
                        $hn_title = get_the_title();
                        $hn_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
                        ?>
                        <li  class="product-thumbnail-outer">
                            <div>
                                <a class="slide_item" href=" <?php echo $hn_permalink  ?> "><img  width="300" height="140" src=" <?php echo $hn_thumbnail ?> " />
                                    <span class="slide_items_details">
                                        <span class="slide_item_title"><?php echo $hn_title ?> </span>
                                        <span class="slide_item_creat"> <?php echo $hn_webcreate ?> </span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <?php
                    // }
                endwhile; 
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode('zf_theme_home_slide','zf_theme_home_slide'); /* pro_Des Copy to Page for Show Blogs */
```

But I only get three products. I don't have any idea that why my code return only three products of all products. How can I fix it?

Comment: add an output of `echo '<pre>';print_r($post_query->request);echo '</pre>';` in question, also make sure you have publish products more than 3.

Comment: Add arg ‘posts_per_page’=> -1

Comment: I used   var_dump( $post_query); and show only 3 lasted products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code you need to add posts per page limit only..

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'product',        /* post type */
  'post_status' => 'publish',   
  'orderby' => 'date',          
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'order' => 'DESC'             
  );
```

Comment: when I used  ""posts_per_page"" i get HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: there was a syntax mistake please check my cod enow